# Trying to tag a question with a blacklisted tag gives a tag creation popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-blocklist

When trying to create a question with a blacklisted tag, it does show the error as expected. However, when trying to post the question, it also shows a popup asking if I want to create the tag:

> [image]

There's likely a bad order check, where the existence of the tag is checked before whether it can be used. Clicking "yes, I'm sure" (not demonstrated in the gif) still returns to the other errors. The error for the bad tag still shows up, though.

While I don't want to test, I assume the question is still blocked if there only are tag-related errors left. The dialog shouldn't be there in either case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed report! We pushed a fix for this yesterday such that blacklisted tags will no longer be picked up in the new tag warning.